# How to specify branch name for shared library as environment variable

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I want to refer/specify (syntax) branch which is set as an environment variable for Jenkins shared library which will be provide during docker container.
For Example:

`@Library(['my-shared-library', BRANCH_NAME])`

Tried using ${BRANCH_NAME} ${env.BRANCH_NAME}

I will provide BRANCH_NAME as environment variable in docker-compose.yml

Also i want to get the env variable effected in org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries.xml

like if i set PIPELINE_VERSION as env variable

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries plugin="workflow-cps-global-lib@2.15">
  <libraries>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryConfiguration>
      <name>XXXXXXXXXXXX</name>
      <retriever class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever">
        <scm class="jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource" plugin="git@3.12.0">
          <id>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</id>
          <remote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</remote>
          <credentialsId>jXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</credentialsId>
          <traits>
            <jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait/>
          </traits>
        </scm>
      </retriever>
      <defaultVersion>${PIPELINE_RELEASE_VERSION}</defaultVersion>
      <implicit>true</implicit>
      <allowVersionOverride>true</allowVersionOverride>
      <includeInChangesets>false</includeInChangesets>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryConfiguration>
  </libraries>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries>
```

Thanks,
Kusuma

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyway it possible to make the environment variable available for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries.xml. But If you use [Jenkins Code As Configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md) plugins, you can pass the variable from docker-compose and make that available to the config file, and when Jenkins load the config file to prepare config for Jenkins would work.
An example can be found [here](https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/tools/tree/main/jenkins/jenkins-dind)